# How to configure Postman so it will generate curl code for Windows

Tags: windows, curl, postman

Postman generates curl code that is not compatible with Windows console. For example, it will generate following curl code for GET https://google.com?q=test:

curl -X GET \
  'http://google.com?q=test' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'

This code cannot be simply copied and pasted into Windows command console as-is. I have to remove backslashes, carriage returns and replace ' with "

Is it possible to configure Postman so it will generate curl code like below?

curl -X GET "http://google.com?q=test" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache"

I'm using Postman application for Windows-64 version 6.1.4

Answer (score 1):

On the "Generate code snippets" modal, there's a "Settings" option.

In order to not have the backslashes/ generate the snippet as oneliner, you need to disable `Generate multiline snippet`.

There is no option to choose if single or double quotation marks.